# Adding a TrackBar control to a ContextMenu

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu, trackbar

Is it possible to add a TrackBar control to a ContextMenu? So when I right click, my ContextMenu will drop down and a TrackBar will appear as a menu item?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your context menu is a `ContexMenuStrip`, you can create an item in this way:

```
[ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.MenuStrip | 
                                   ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.ContextMenuStrip)]
public class TrackBarMenuItem : ToolStripControlHost
{
    private TrackBar trackBar;

    public TrackBarMenuItem():base(new TrackBar())
    {
        this.trackBar = this.Control as TrackBar;
    }

    // Add properties, events etc. you want to expose...
}
```

Thanks to the `ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability` attribute, you can even see the item in the Forms Designer, as shown in the image below:

[image]

**P.S.**
This solution comes from this [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k5etstz.aspx)

Comment: Edited to add designer support

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to set the context menu to user draw and draw the menu items yourself. You will have to create a custom MenuItem the implementes a TrackBar

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth for anyone who stumbles across this having problems with:

> Constructor on type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripControlHost' not found.

The only way I got it to work was by putting the derived control in it's own file.  When it is in the same file as another control it confuses the designer.