# ToolstripTextBox customisation

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, custom-controls, toolstrip

I would like to develop a custom Toolstrip control. The control would be like a ToolStrip but with the following features :

- The textbox would be proceeded by a label
- The textbox would have two buttons after it.

I guess to implement this then a user drawn control would be required. Does anyone know of any resources available on the web to get me started on this.

Comment: digEmAll - looks interesting, I'll take a look and see if it will work out for me.

Comment: I've turned my comment into an answer :)

Comment: If you would like to make toolstriptextbox stretch over all available distance, here is a good example, helped me a lot   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404304(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should compose your usercontrol with label, textbox and buttons, exposing all the necessary Properties.

Here's a [MSDN WalkThrough for UserControls creation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Then, use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339143/adding-a-trackbar-control-to-a-contextmenu/4339544#4339544) (or this [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k5etstz.aspx)) to create the custom `ToolStripItem`, just replace the `TrackBar` with you custom control.

**P.S.**
If you don't want to create a `ToolStripItem`, but just a popup showing your custom control, you can use [this other example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171640/dropdown-menu-with-scrollbar-in-net/3172041#3172041), replacing the ListBox with your control.

Comment: @BENBUN Coder: added another example ;)