# Why doesn't this ToolStripControlHost work?

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripcontrolhost

I'm trying to emulate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4339544/939213) answer but though this works:

```
public class TrackBarMenuItem : ToolStripControlHost
{
    TrackBar trackBar;
    public TrackBarMenuItem()
        : base(new TrackBar())
    {
        trackBar = Control as TrackBar;
    }
}
```

This doesn't:

```
public class PanelMenuItem : ToolStripControlHost
{
    Panel panel;
    public PanelMenuItem()
        : base(new Panel())
    {
        panel = Control as Panel;
        Visible = true;
        Enabled = true;
        panel.AutoSize = false;
        panel.Size = new Size(100, 50);
    }
}
```

Why?

I'm calling them like this:

```
contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(new TrackBarMenuItem());
contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(new PanelMenuItem());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the minimum size of the Panel:

```
public class PanelMenuItem : ToolStripControlHost {
  Panel panel;
  public PanelMenuItem()
    : base(new Panel()) {
    panel = Control as Panel;
    Visible = true;
    Enabled = true;
    panel.AutoSize = false;
    panel.Size = new Size(100, 50);

    panel.MinimumSize = panel.Size;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. (So does that mean that context menu's always use the minimum size?)

Comment: @ispiro It's the `ToolStripControlHost` that has issues with size of the control that it hosts.  On some controls like Panel, it needs to have the `MinimumSize` set in order for it to be viewable.